# Remove only click events from an element

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

#### How I can prevent any click event that has been assigned to an element?

I'm using a user custom javascript to alter a website. That script runs after the webpage is loaded.

How can I prevent a click event that has been bind to an element from triggering?

The binding procedure is opaque so I can't get the reference of the function. Also, element also has some other events bind to it, I want to keep them.

I simulated this situation with this snippet. I want `hovering` is shown when hovers but `click` is not shown while clicking. Is this possible?

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

(() => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked'));
  button.addEventListener('mouseover', () => console.log('hovering'));
})();

// What do I do here to prevent the click event from being triggered?
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Naively, I'd say `button.removeEventListener('click')` ? Did you try that?

Comment: Toggle the pointerevents if you do not want to remove the event listener

Comment: Maybe duplicated, see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-in-javascript-or-in-debugging?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event is dispatched in two phases, the default phase is the second one, "bubbling", so in this case you can add a listener in the first phase, "capturing", by setting the third parameter to `true` and stop the event from reaching the second phase:

```js
button.addEventListener('click', e => e.stopPropagation(), true);
```

Comment: Wow it actually works! I didn't know you can stop propagating from functions binded afterward, you saved my day!